# Unable to access Kubernetes Dashboard via kubeconfig

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm trying to access Kubernetes Dashboard via a kubeconfig file but I don't know how to create a kubeconfig file to access it.

I can access it by a token way but I want to access it by a kubeconfig file, too.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you mean when you say you can access it by token but not through a kubeconfig? Kubeconfigs simply store authentication information in them, which can include authentication via a token.
Assuming the rest of your kubeconfig file is populated, you just need to modify it so that your user information contains the token, like so:

```
users:
- name: my-user
  user:
    token: <token-here>
```

Comment: could you tell me please that how to get Kubernetes username and token exactly?

Comment: You mentioned in your question that you can access it by token. That token is associated with some user account or service account, so you need to look at how you got the token you're using.

Comment: I have a token but it only worked via token way. when I created the kubeconfig file and inserted into the token and my username, it didn't work. How to assigned a token to a user?